# for loop in R that involves 2 columns in a dataframe at a time

Tags: r, loops

I am new to loops and am trying to conduct an operation that involves 2 columns in a dataframe. For example:

```
a = rnorm(6) 
b = rnorm(6) 
c = rnorm(6)
d = rnorm(6)
e = rnorm(6)
f = rnorm(6)
df = data.frame(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

I want to loop through `df` such that I can create a new variable `w` that is a list. Each value of `w` is the product of the mean of 2 columns.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by Each value of w is the product of the mean of 2 columns?

Comment: yes to @Zhiya, what is the expected output to look like?